# Figure out the PID of exact node.js application

Tags: bash, grep, process, ps, node.js

Here is an output of my ps aux:

```
ps aux | grep "node"
root      2501  0.0  3.4 720400 68512 ?        Sl   16:09   0:03 node /etc/skbx/host/skbx.js 8081 tula13 8082 8084 8085 10.8.0.6
root     20586  0.0  0.1  17396  2664 pts/16   S+   21:29   0:00 grep --color=auto node
```

Disregard the second one, we have a node process. I need to figure out in bash the PID of the node process that is executing skbx.js exactly.

How could I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In general, if you are looking for the PID of a known command line, `pgrep` is preferable to `ps | grep` because you don't need to filter the output to extract the PID. You can use `pgrep` with `-f` to match the full command line:

```
pgrep -f 'node /etc/skbx/host/skbx.js'
```

You can also target processes by parent process ID and controlling terminal, among other criteria.

If you don't have `pgrep` installed, you can use `grep` in a pipeline. In the following example, we use a character class in the pattern supplied to `grep` to prevent `grep` itself from appearing in the output. This is less typing than piping the output to `grep -v grep` or similar:

```
ps aux | grep '[n]ode /etc/skbx/host/skbx.js' | awk '{print $2}'
```

The `grep` command listed in the `ps` output will include square bracket literals which are not matched in the resulting pattern used by `grep`.